# scraping data that updates every month

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I've been trying to scrape data, but I got stuck because I don't know how to do it. So I want to scrape usd idr price monthly in this website https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=01&MM1=08&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=08&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21 but with 25 years span that updates everymonth. this is my code, in this code I'm scraping data from august 1995 until august 2020(25 years) but it's not updating everymonth. So I want next month will be `september 1995 until september` 2020.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(
    "https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=01&MM1=09&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=09&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21", header=0)[-3]
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"])
df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['month', 'average', 'min', 'max', 'nb_working_days']
df.to_csv("data_usd.csv", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)
print(df)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "its not updating everymonth"? 
Can you give a precise example of what you are expecting  VS what you are getting?

Comment: what i want is the data is updating every month with 25 years span,bcs there is always new data in new month,like in previous month im getting the data from august 1995 until august 2020 (manually scraping) and this month i want the data updating itself from october 1995 until october 2020

Comment: There's nothing in your code that does the required update you mention.

Comment: yeah i actually update it with task scheduler from windows,so when i run that task it will scraping automatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the data for octobers, here's what you do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html(
    "https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=01&MM1=09&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2=09&YYYY2=2020&btnOK=Go%21", header=0)[-3]
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"])
df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['month', 'average', 'min', 'max', 'nb_working_days']
df.to_csv("data_usd.csv", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")


indexes_to_drop = []

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.month.split("-")[1] != '10':
        indexes_to_drop.append(index)

df.drop(index=indexes_to_drop, inplace = True)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

print(df)
```

//EDIT: Ah I think i'm getting it! You can set the displayed interval in the URL. This will get you the results from this month to this month in 1995

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.today()


df = pd.read_html(
    f"https://fxtop.com/en/historical-exchange-rates.php?A=1&C1=USD&C2=IDR&MA=1&DD1=01&MM1={dt.month}&YYYY1=1995&B=1&P=&I=1&DD2=23&MM2={dt.month}&YYYY2={dt.year}&btnOK=Go%21", header=0)[-3]
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Month"])
df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
df.columns = ['month', 'average', 'min', 'max', 'nb_working_days']
df.to_csv("data_usd.csv", index=False)
df = pd.read_csv("data_usd.csv")


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0]+1)

print(df)
```

Comment: hello! there is mistake in my question! what i really want is scrape data monthly with 25 years span in previous month im sraping manually from august 1995 until august 2020,is there any help if i want to update data everymonth like in this month i must getting october 1995-until october 2020.

Comment: thank you so much! but with that code im only getting october 1995 until january 2020,thank you once again!

Comment: yeah check again there was a slight mistake. Is it important for you that its always day 23? because by beginning of november you will probably get an error until november 23rd

Comment: thank you so muchhh!!!!!! i hope i can be better like you !

Comment: yeah, please accept the answer then as correct if it fits for you :)

Comment: hello mr! im back again with problem,do you knw why when i try to run the py file i got the data from 1967 instead not from 1995. do you know what problem is? thank you

Comment: hello mr! im back again with problem,do you knw why when i try to run the py file i got the data from 1967 instead not from 1995. do you know what problem is? thank you @Alexander Riedel